Efficient Methods for Approximating High-Dimensional Integrals with Gaussian-Like Factors
I'm seeking a computationally efficient method to approximately evaluate high-dimensional integrals of the form:
$$\int f(\textbf{x}) \prod_i g_i(x_i) \, d\textbf{x}$$
where $f(\mathbf{x}) = (\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x})^{-k}$ with $k$ being a large integer and $\mathbf{x}$ typically being of dimension $n > 5,000$. The functions $g_i(x_i)$ are probability density functions and can be approximated by Gaussian distributions $\mathcal{N}(x_i; \mu_i, \tau_i)$, since Laplace approximations to $g_i(x_i)$ are straightforward to derive. In general, $g_i(x_i)$ can be assumed to have a simple and tractable univariate form and is easy to sample from.
Things I've tried so far:

Monte Carlo integration: While sampling from $g_i(x_i)$ is straightforward, convergence is extremely slow. In general, sampling-based methods are likely not feasible due to the high computational cost.

Laplace approximation: This method is impractical because the structure of $\mathbf{A}$, the behavior of $f(\mathbf{x})$ (which spikes to infinity when $\mathbf{x} = 0$), and the high dimensionality make finding the mode of the integrand in a computationally cheap manner very challenging.

Focusing on $g_i(x_i)$: When all $\tau_i$ are small, a Laplace approximation at the approximate integrand mode $\mathbf{\mu}$ or even simply using $\int f(\mathbf{x}) \prod_i g_i(x_i) \, d\mathbf{x} \approx (\mathbf{\mu}'\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\mu})^{-k}$ are quite effective. However, assuming small $\tau_i$ for all $i$ is not always possible.

Direct approximation: Attempting to approximate the density of the random variable $\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}$ given a Gaussian approximation for $g(\mathbf{x})$, and then estimating the $k$-th negative moment of the resulting distribution, is somewhat effective, but the results are not satisfactory.


I'm curious if there are any specific techniques or tricks that could be employed, given the $g_i(x_i)$ are (approximately) Gaussian and independent. Are there other approximation methods that might be computationally feasible given the structure of this problem? Any suggestions or hints in alternative directions would be greatly appreciated!

Low-rank approximation of $A$? Monte Carlo integration via Hamiltonian MCMC (maybe converges better than whatever you're currently using)?  Variational approximation?

Thanks! By construction, \mathbf{A} has full rank. I sometimes use HMC to better understand the structure of the integrand, which works up to around 250 dimensions and even then requires significant time. I’ll look into variational approximations!
